# Embeddable js interpreter for user's code?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Imagine website, where user can generate content via js.
For example.

1. User clicks button
2. It requests our api (not user's api)
3. Api returns object with specific fields.
4. We show `select` with user's defined options generated by user's code or some calculated result based on data we sent.

The idea is to give user an ability to edit visible content (using our structures, we know beforehand which fields in returned object do what things).

First solution "developed" in 5 minutes.

1. Users clicks button
2. It send all required data as `context` to our api.
3. We fetch from database user's defined code

```js
// here is the code which we write (not user) and we know this code is safe
const APP_CONTEXT = parseInput(); // this can be parameters from command line
const ourLibrary = require('ourLibrary');
// APP_CONTEXT is variable which contains data from frontend. We control data inside APP_CONTEXT, user can not write to it
// here is user defined code
const someVar = APP_CONTEXT['fieldDescribedInOurDocumentation'];
const anotherVar = APP_CONTEXT['anotherFieldFromDocumentation'];
ourLibrary.sendToFrontend(someVar + anotherVar);
```

In this very simple example once user clicked on button, we sent api request to our api, user's code has been executed, we show result of execution. `ourLibrary` abstract the way the handling is completed.

The main problem as I think is the security. I think about using restricted nodejs process. No network access, no file system access.

Is it possible to deny any import/require in nodejs process? I want to let user only call all builtin js function (Math.min, Math.max, new Date(), +, -), declare functions and so on. So it will work like a sophisticated calculator. And also we should have an ability to send it back to frontend. For example, via rabbitmq + nodejs + websockets. We can use simple `console.log` if former is the problem.

Some possible solution (not secure, of course) using nodejs interpreter. We execute interpreter every time when action is required.

```js
const APP_CONTEXT = parseInput();
const ourLibrary = require('ourLibrary');
const usersCode = getUsersCode();
eval(usersCode);
```

Inside usersCode they use `ourLibrary.sendToFrontend` to produce the result. But this solution allows user to use any builtin nodejs functions, like `const fs = require('fs')`. Of course access will be restricted using linux system (selinux or similar) but can I configure/setup nodejs to run as simple js interpreter? May be there is some other js interpreter exists which is safe to use? Safe means: only arithmetic, Date function, Math functions and so on. No filesystem access, no network access.

Comment: "*I want to let user only call all builtin js function (Math.min, Math.max, new Date(), +, -), declare functions and so on.*" note that even if you successfully isolate the user (no network requests, no access to the file system, no importing libraries, etc), then a malicious user can still simply write `for(;;);` and submit an infinite loop. It's going to be working isolated but waste your server's resources. A more sophisticated attack would use a more expensive computation but it doesn't really matter - the result is DOSing the server by exhausting its resources.

Comment: You should look into utilities and tools for sandboxing JS and/or processes in general. I can't recommend any but I know they exist. This should allow you to restrict the process running user code from 1. interacting with the system (e.g., it's effectively "offline" and no access to the disk) 2. restrict the usage of resources - give it less access to the CPU and memory 3. Time limit the process, so it doesn't run forever. Even if somebody tries to DOS with wasted computation, it's going to work for a limited time.